# Paypal express checkout for client side integration

Tags: jquery, ios, paypal, uiwebview, express-checkout

I have integrated PayPal client side express checkout in a web app. Using ios web view I have created an app. Now whenever I click the PayPal checkout modal pops up and closes itself immediately. I'm facing these issue on ios version 10.3 and above.
The checkout works fine for all devices below 10.3 devices.

Kindly help me with a solution.

here is the code

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>

// Render the PayPal button

paypal.Button.render({

    // Set your environment

    env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

    // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
    // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

    client: {
        sandbox:    'XXXXXX,
        production: 'XXXXXX'
    },

    // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

    payment: function() {

        // Make a client-side call to the REST api to create the payment

        return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                }
            ]
        });
    },

    // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

        // Execute the payment

        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container').innerText = 'Payment Complete!';
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button-container');

</script>`
```

Comment: Please provide some code of yours. The information you provided will likely not suffice for providing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enter your app client ID into your code:

```
 client: {
        sandbox:    'AVEqB1ga85Bzn8r8o5cckJN7peyaPgQy1zzH748iCwMGuVQN8jtZP8i0gV5ghuolgJsUe7JoMcjwsqrC,
        production: 'XXXXXX'
 },
```